# Changing numbering of chapters, sections and subsections in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I need to build a table of contents in latex, where the chapters are as
roman numerals, sections are arabic numbers, and the subsections are letters. I also need it to only go up to the subsection level.

It should look like this:

```
I. CHAPTER
II. CHAPTER
   1. Section
   2. Section
      (a) Subsection
      (b) Subsection
```

I use the following command to generate the table of contents but It does it with another format.

```
\tableofcontents
```

How do I achieve this with latex?

Ted.

Comment: Do the `chapters`, `sections`, etc have the numbering scheme you've illustrated, or something else? For example, are your `chapters` actually `CHAPTER 1`, `CHAPTER 2`, etc, and you want them to look differently in the `toc`?

Answer (score 13):

You can redefine the commands `\thechapter`, `\thesection`, `\thesubsection` which control the representation of the counters for chapters, sections, and subsections. The `tocloft` package can be then used to add the dots:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{.}
\renewcommand\cftsecaftersnum{.}

\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{(\alph{subsection})}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\section{Test Section One}
\section{Test Section One}
\subsection{Test Subsection A}
\subsection{Test Subsection B}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some other adjustments might be necessary, to prevent the chapter number from overlapping the title, and perhaps reducing the space between the section number and their titles; those adjustments can be something like:

```
\renewcommand\cftchapnumwidth{2.8em}
\renewcommand\cftsecnumwidth{2em}
\renewcommand\cftsecindent{3em}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecindent{5em}
```

Comment: This does not work in a beamer